# How can I retrieve the elements out of a <tr using twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using a table to display rows of data from PHP/mySQL code.

I want to click on the table row to pop up a modal form containing more information than what I see in the table row.

How do I reference the data array $detail in the data-source variable, and take each element and place it in a modal?

```
echo '<tr name="'.$id.'" width="100%" class="btn-lg" data-id="'.$id.'"    
data-source="'.$detail).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">';
```

here is my javascript fragment to handle the onclick of the :

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  var startAt = $(this);
 // how do I retrieve the values inside the array from data-source="'.$detail).'"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo '<tr name="'.$id.'" width="100%" class="btn-lg" data-id="'.$id.'"    
data-source="'.$detail).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">';
```

To:

```
echo '<tr name="'.$id.'" width="100%" class="btn-lg" data-id="'.$id.'"    
data-source=\''.htmlentities(json_encode($detail, true)).'\' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">';
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var startAt = $(this),
        sourceData = $.parseJSON($(this).data('source'));
}
```

You can get rid of `htmlentities` if you know that there will be no data in this array with a `'` in it.

Comment: This is my table row:  <tr class="btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-arr="[{"rec":{"id":"2","rFINumber":"RFI002","type":"1","projectId":"21","authorId":"2","messageTitle":"Response to message #1","message":"Amin response to the first message.","dateCreated":"2014-01-09 11:12:18","dateSent":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","replyExpected":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","overdue":"0","isActive":"0","status":"0"}}]" data-id="2" width="100%" data-target="#myModal">
<td>RFI002</td>
<td>Response to message #1</td>
</tr>

Comment: the arttribute for `data-arr` can't be wrapped in `"` it must be `'` like `data-arr=''`